# Scrapy and Splash don't crawl

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, splash-screen

I made a crawler, splash is working (i tested it in my browser), scrapy though can't crawl and extract items.

My actual code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.http.headers import Headers
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from oddsportal.items import OddsportalItem



class OddbotSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "oddbot"
    allowed_domains = ["oddsportal.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/tennis/',
    )

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
            'splash': {
                'endpoint': 'render.html',
                'args': {'wait': 5.5}
            }
        })

    def parse(self, response):
        item = OddsportalItem()
        print response.body
```

Comment: what's the output of `response.body`?

Comment: `print response.body`?

Comment: it prints nothing: i edited with the actual code

Answer (score 0):

Try importing scrap_splash and call new request through SplashRequest as:

```
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

yield SplashRequest(url, endpoint='render.html', args={'any':any})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should modify CrawlSpider

```
def _requests_to_follow(self, response):
    if not isinstance(response, (HtmlResponse, SplashJsonResponse, SplashTextResponse)):
        return
    seen = set()
    for n, rule in enumerate(self._rules):
        links = [lnk for lnk in rule.link_extractor.extract_links(response)
                 if lnk not in seen]
        if links and rule.process_links:
            links = rule.process_links(links)
        for link in links:
            seen.add(link)
            r = self._build_request(n, link)
            yield rule.process_request(r)
```